# Custom entities in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using EF6 in my ASP.NET Core 2.0

I have `Foo` table as :

```
Foo(ID,NAME)
```

and `Bar` as

```
Bar(ID,FOO_ID,TYPE)
```

and a view just like this :

```
Create View GETFooBar 
as 

select F.ID FOO_ID,F.NAME FOO_NAME,B.TYPE FOO_TYPE from Foo F join Bar B 
on F.ID = B.FOO_ID
```

Can I do the following:

```
public Class FooBar{
     public int FooId;
     public string Name;
     public string Type;
}
```

and get the result of view just like this?

```
  var fooBars= context.Database.SqlQuery<GETFooBar>( 
                       "SELECT * FROM GETBarFoo").ToList();
```

Comment: You have the right idea. However, the view's column names need to align with the property names on the class you're binding to. In other words, `Name` will be null, because `FOO_NAME` will not be considered a value for that property. It should just be `NAME` or you need to change your property to something like `Foo_Name`. The names are case-insensitive though, FWIW.